# Convert entire playlist from m4a to mp3

Tags: directory, vlc, mp3, convert, m4a

I have a ton of music on my computer, but unfortunately it's in m4a, and steam only takes mp3.

Is there a program or a terminal command that will convert an entire folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was fairly simple. First you'll need `ffmpeg` installed.

Then there's this simple terminal command you can use to convert all the audio files to MP3:

```
for f in *.flac , *.m4a , *.ogg ; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -ab 320k "${f%.m4a}.mp3"; done
```

Breakdown:

- `for f in *.flac , *.m4a , *.ogg ;`: For every audio file of these types,
- `do ffmpeg -i "$f" -ab 320k "${f%.flac}.mp3";`: Convert that file to MP3, get the next file.
- If you want to change the bitrate, simply change the `320k` in kbps.
- You can change the filetypes it looks for simply with that comma-separated list of `*.flac , *.m4a , *.ogg` to whatever files ffmpeg can decode.
- You can change the output name to whatever you want, `"${f%.m4a}.mp3"` could be `"${f%}.mp3"` or "${f%.audio}.mp3", f% represents the original filename.

Comment: how do i specify the path?

Comment: @thebluesquirel Simply `cd directory` first, so that you are in the directory where the music files are, then issue the command. To do another folder, just `cd` to that folder and run it again.

Comment: ok thanks wasnt sure if i had to specify it in the command ,or if it would make the changes to the current directory.

Comment: Just a note: avconv can replace ffmpeg straight away in this command.